# Google Map not displaying on new events

Tags: civievent, location, map

I have just upgraded our CiviCRM install to 4.7.13. When creating a new event and selecting all relevant options, the Google Map is not displayed. This IS displayed when viewing other active and older events.

We have been using a custom .tpl file, but even after disabling the tpl and clearing the cache(s) we are still facing the same issue.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

For testing we are using the same stored address. The existing, pre-upgrade event has the following values:

```
{$event.is_map} = 1
{$config->mapProvider} = Google
{$location.address.1.geo_code_1} = 56.0797664
{$location.address.1.city} = Dunfermline
{$location.address.1.state_province} = NULL
```

The map is displayed.

A new event, post-upgrade, with exactly the same settings has the following:

```
{$event.is_map} = 1
{$config->mapProvider} = Google
{$location.address.1.geo_code_1} = NULL
{$location.address.1.city} = Dunfermline
{$location.address.1.state_province} = NULL
```

The map is missing.

When we open the location information on the old event and save, the map fails to work ?!

Comment: *The same stored address* does that mean the same record (thus a record in civicrm_addresses), or the same entity (the same combination of address fields, but stored in a different record in the database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also seen this problem, and fixed it. It's nothing to do with CiviCRM at all - it's a recent change made by Google regarding their API and your authorisation to use it.  Existing users seem to be OK, but new users (ie. one of my clients) or maybe even new maps seem to be affected.  You should review your  authorisation to use the Google API for your domain.  It's a slightly confusing situation because it appears that you don't need to enter your API key on Civi anymore, but you do need to be authorised by Google.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with a 4.7.12. I workarounded marking `Override automatic geocoding` and setting `latitud` and `longitud` coordinates manually.